# Changing a DNS master

Tags: domain-name-system

I need to change a DNS master by a new one (and it's quite new for me). I took an existing domain (not important one), remove the DNS master and change it by the new one. Even after few days, the dns change is not completely propagated. I got a mix between new config (new DNS master + old secondary DNS) and old config (old master + old secondary).

Looking in the old master DNS logs, I have seen this:

```
client 213.251.188.141#27325: query (cache) 'example.com/SOA/IN' denied
client 213.251.188.141#45773: bad zone transfer request: 'example.com/IN': non-authoritative zone (NOTAUTH)
client 213.251.188.141#36912: query (cache) 'example.com/SOA/IN' denied
```

The IP is one of the IPs defined in "allow-transfer" in the config of the old master DNS.

The example.com domain has been removed from the config file too. So I do not understand why I still got entries in log for that.

On the new master DNS, I do not have error messages.

Thx for your help!

Comment: Could you add the SOA field values ? There is the server master stored in it

Comment: The `MNAME` field in the SOA record [is not reliable in current practice](http://serverfault.com/a/85436/152073). (particularly due to hidden masters)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the issue. The secondary DNS (which is an OVH one) was still linked to the old master DNS. And so the secondary DNS has 2 zons defined for the same domain ... After cleaning it, it works well!

Thx!